# Scan array for 3 consecutive numbers that sum to 7

Tags: ruby

> Write a function `lucky_sevens?(numbers)`, which takes in an array of
>   integers and returns true if any three consecutive elements sum to 7.
>
> ```
> lucky_sevens?([2,1,5,1,0]) == true # => 1 + 5 + 1 == 7
> lucky_sevens?([0,-2,1,8]) == true # => -2 + 1 + 8 == 7
> lucky_sevens?([7,7,7,7]) == false
> lucky_sevens?([3,4,3,4]) == false
> ```
>
> Make sure your code correctly checks for edge cases (i.e. the first
>   and last elements of the array).

While my code does seem to work (I did some test cases), I know it can be improved. There's no reason to have double `puts` and return statements. I'm also wondering if there are general improvements to the syntax itself that can make it much more readable.

```
def lucky_sevens?(numbers)
  i = 0
  while i < numbers.length - 2

    if numbers[i] + numbers[i + 1] + numbers[i + 2] == 7
        puts true
        return true
    end
    i+=1
    end 
    puts false
    return false
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code, is way too imperative to be idiomatic Ruby.

The only reasonable improvement is re-writing it from scratch:

```
def lucky_sevens?(numbers)
  groups_of_three(numbers)
    .any? {|group| group.inject(:+) == 7}
end
```

Knowing that `inject(:+)` means `sum`, this reads like English. Implementing `groups_of_three` is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Could the downvoter explain why? I am always happy to receive constructive criticism :)

Answer (score 4):

Looping using an index is not idiomatic in Ruby.  Looping using `#each` and `Enumerable` methods based on `#each` are much more common.  This is a perfect opportunity to use [`Enumerable#each_cons(3)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons).

```
def lucky_sevens?(numbers)
  numbers.each_cons(3) { |group| return true if group.reduce(:+) == 7 }
  false
end
```

The problem doesn't ask you to print anything, so don't.

Comment: Writing `groups_of_three` was left as an exercise for the reader :o,  showing the right built-in right away in my opinion seems to encourage laziness...

Comment: Don't use my `return true if …`. @Caridorc's `any?` is much better.

Comment: @200_success, In fairness, your version is more performant as it will return immediately upon finding a success, whereas the `any?` version requires all groups of three to be calculated, even if, say, the first 3 numbers in the array summed to 7

Comment: Also, depending on your context, the `false` return value at the end may be unnecessary, since `each_cons` returns `nil`, which will evaluate to false.

Comment: @Jonah `Enumeration#any?` does short-circuit. You can see that `[3,2,1,0].each_cons(3).any? { |group| 1 / group.min }` succeeds, while `[2,1,0].each_cons(3).any? { |group| 1 / group.min }` crashes.

Comment: @200_success, Ah, good point.  I was thinking `each_cons` would create the full array -- I forgot it returns an Enumerator which is lazy

Comment: @Caridorc Laziness is a virtue of developers.